# Can't upgrade geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas

I looked at the documentation for geopandas.

https://geopandas.org/en/v0.4.0/install.html

Apparent, this is how you install geopandas: `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`

I tried that and I'm getting version .9, but the newest version seems to be .12, but I can't seem to upgrade my version of geopandas. Also, when I try to run this: `geopandas.sjoin_nearest`

I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: module 'geopandas' has no attribute 'sjoin_nearest'`

Has anyone experienced this? Is there some kind of work-around?

Comment: Why are you reading such an old version of the docs?

Answer (score 0):

## Install

Looking at the `latest` version of the [docs](https://geopandas.org/en/latest/getting_started/install.html) (you can change version on readthedocs.io in the bottom left of the viewport), we can see that there is a new, simpler, install method:

```
conda install geopandas
```

or, via `pip`:

```
pip install geopandas
```

(note there are additional dependencies to install when downloading from `pip`).

## Upgrade

To upgrade a `conda` package:

```
conda upgrade [package]
```

e.g

```
conda upgrade geopandas
```

To upgrade a `pip` package:

```
pip install --upgrade [package]
```

e.g.

```
pip install --upgrade geopandas
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you can specify the version that you want to install. Ultimately this is the only thing that worked for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge geopandas=0.10
```